# Laravel RouteNotFoundException Route [logout] not defined

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-9

I found that issue in my Laravel project. I'm a newbie and use Laravel version 9.26, but I get the following error.

> Symfony \ Component \ Routing \ Exception \ RouteNotFoundException
> Route [logout] not defined

**web.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

Route::get('/', [LoginController::class, 'login'])
    ->name('login');
Route::post('actionlogin', [LoginController::class, 'actionlogin'])
    ->name('actionlogin');
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])
    ->name('home')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('actionlogout', [LoginController::class, 'actionlogout'])
    ->name('actionlogout')->middleware('auth');
```

**LoginController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Session;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('home');
        } else {
            return view('login');
        }
    }

    public function actionlogin(Request $request)
    {
        $data = [
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => $request->input('password'),
        ];

        if (Auth::Attempt($data)) {
            return redirect('home');
        } else {
            Session::flash('error', 'Email atau Password Salah');
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }

    public function actionlogout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

When I type: localhost/8k/login or localhost/8k/home, the result is always the same.

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you likely have `route('logout')` (or similar), but you named your route `->name('actionLogout')`, so you'll need to fix that so both are `logout` or `actionLogout`

Comment: yeah thank you bro. I've been noticed it. and I have make right to the script.
but the error went to : Route [login] not defined.

Comment: that `namespace App\Http\Controllers` should not be in web.php.

Comment: I've search for the login route but everything seems to be okay.
previously I use this script for login are fine.

Comment: You're actually overriding your `login` route with `home`: `Route::get('/', [LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('login');` and `Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home')->middleware('auth');`, notice how those are both `Route::get('/', ...)`? The 2nd one overrides the first, which is `->name('login')`, with `->name('home')`; you'll need to fix that too; you can only have 1 `Route::get()` definition for `'/'` (you can have multiple verbs, like `Route::get('/', ...)` and `Route::post('/', ...)`, but not multiple `Route::get()`)

Comment: yeah I think you're right,
let me fix this first and see what happened next.
thank you so much for your answer. I can't close the case for now till it fixed so maybe some one outside there who face the same issue would get helped. thankyou